# How to use javac with jars and packages

Tags: java, compilation, javac

I'm trying to run java from the command line, and haven't had to include extra packages with the javac command before and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I'm running `javac -d bin -cp jar1:jar2:...:jarN:PackageName MyClass.java` but I'm still getting an error: `package PackageName does not exist`

I'm using the absolute paths for everything, and I also tried individually listing the java files inside the package but that didn't work either.  I'm using a colon since I'm on a mac.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong?  Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I needed to compile the java files in PackageName before I could compile MyClass.java, which depended on them.  So what I needed to do was: `javac -d bin -cp jar1:jar2:...:jarN PackageName/*.java` and then I could compile MyClass.java with bin added to the classpath as well as the jars.